# Landsat 8/9 level-2 pansharpening

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-8, satellite, pansharpening

From the [USGS website states](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-landsat-archives-landsat-8-9-olitirs-collection-2-level-2) "Landsat 8 OLI Band 8 (panchromatic band) is not processed to Top-of Atmosphere or Surface Reflectance."  Obviously same is true for Landsat 9.  I.e., it's not available at level-2 processing.  [ESRI](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-of-panchromatic-sharpening.htm) shows some ways to do pansharpening, and [Sentinel-hub](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/faq/#how-do-i-manually-pansharpen-specific-band-eg-red) offers this as well, but it's not clear to me if/how one could take the level-1 panchromatic band and pansharpen level-2 data.